# How to show a continuous variable according to 2 categorical variables on the chart? Python

Tags: pandas, plot

I try to show a lot of things on the chart.
How to show a continuous variable according to 2 categorical variables on the chart? I have to make a chart because this table is illegible.

```
import pandas as pd

cc =[1, 2, 3, 4,5]
Group = ['Early Stage Alzheimers', 'Early Stage Alzheimers', 'Middle Stage Alzheimers','Early Stage Alzheimers', 'Early Stage Alzheimers']
variable = ['Piano Interlude','Easy Listening','Mozart','Mozart','Easy Listening']
value = ['18','24','18','12','19']
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': cc, 'Group': 

Group,'variable':variable, 'value':value})

df
```

[image]

Comment: `pd.pivot('Group', 'variable', 'value')`?

Comment: I need a plot - not pivot

Comment: Then chain plot to it?